# Alternatives to "Like", "+1", "Bookmark", and "Favorite"?

Tags: terminology, copywriting, activity-feed

I'm building a web-app where users indicate that they "like" feed-items published by other users. The act of "liking" also inherently bookmarks the feed-item as well as the publishing user. I'm wondering if there are other verbs that I can use to represent this action. Below are some options I've considered

- Like: Too facebooky, does not signify anything about bookmarking for future use
- Bookmark: Doesn't necessarily indicate "liking"
- Favorite
- Tag

I'd like to if there are other (or one of the above) that suits this purpose better

Comment: A star is also often used. "Star this"

Comment: "Like" and "+1" would be bad terms as, to me at least, they don't suggest any sort of permanence or bookmarking. Bookmarking, on the other hand, doesn't necessarily suggest liking. For example, I have various websites bookmarked without especially *liking* them: they just perform necessary tasks.

Comment: Just consider a **-1**, please. One of my pet-peeves about Facebook is that post that is simply incorrect eventually gets +1'd by enough idiots. Sometimes, negative feedback is required. (Of course, this might not make sense for your app.)

Comment: Perhaps "pin" would be a good name.

Comment: Perhaps "Subscribe"?

Comment: I can not answer, but if I could, I would say: "Heart this". The negative side is translating it. "Star this" is good in English  but also has the translation problem. Try to translate "Star this" or "Heart this" to a Latin language and you will experience what I am talking about.

Comment: One consideration is that while most of these words are consistent across variations in English, "Favorite" is jarring for people in countries where it's spelt "favourite"

Comment: Please consider liking and saving as different features. I don't want to save everything I like nor like everything that I save (for later or for good)

Comment: For what it's worth, I "favourite" tweets, not because they're my favourite tweets ever, but because there's absolutely no other way I can make a note to go back and watch the attached video later.

Comment: I kinda feel like "Tag" works for both. It makes me feel like I'm saving something for later (the bookmark) and also like I'm promoting it for other users (liking). And, like @verbose-mode said, "star" often works in most situations I can think of... though I wouldn't implicitly think I am bookmarking it, were that the case.

Answer (score 88):

"Like" is Facebook's creation and is strongly associated with Facebook. +1 is Google+'s creation and is totally associated with its brand.

Thinking out of the box... It seems your functionality is not exactly the same as "liking". It's more "like & follow". There is no single word for that, so alternatively you could invent your own vocabulary. Similarly to a "tweet" being a twitter result, you could invent your own word, possibly derived from your webapp's name. Suppose you web app is named "Grease", you could have a "Grease this!" button, or a "Grease" button or whatever. A Greasee could then be a feed item that was marked with the "Grease" button.

Before you know it all the kids in the street will be talking about their Grease and Greasees and how much they are Greasing every day.

Comment: I think to "Star" something is typically used to encompass "like & follow".

Comment: I think the term "Follow" is good - it gets over the idea of both approval and the fact that you wish to continue to be 'part of the gang'.

Comment: I think +1 is far more associated with StackExchange's upvote/downvote arrows than G+...

Comment: @Izkata for people on StackExcahnge, perhaps. But Google is far more popular, and they explicitly label the "button" as "+1", while SE uses arrows. "+1" is just used by the commenters to indicate they are explaining their vote.

Comment: Maybe you should call it a woof :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wfG8ngFvPk&feature=kp

Comment: It makes me think of the blog of David Lee where the readers can "kudo" the article if you keep the cursor in the circle : http://daslee.me/good-listeners

Comment: An item on fire could be grease lightening!

Comment: +1 for not only telling to invent a word but also giving an example!

Comment: @drusepth: I only know "star" from GitHub and it doesn't imply "follow". Quite the contrary. The old system only had "follow" (or "watch") and introduced "star" so that people can show their appreciation for a project without cluttering their feed.

Comment: [PORK IT!](http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/comics/websites_stop/3.png) from [8 websites you need to stop making](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/websites_stop).

Comment: I *hate* custom vocabulary on sites like this. It absolutely reeks of trying too hard to be "hip", and is reminiscent of that annoying period where web-based companies were referred to as "dot-coms". When zwinkiepop.com (or whatever) asks me to "Zwinkie This!" I run like the wind, and if somebody actually uses the term in communication, I immediately want to harm them. Also, incidentally, we like to call people who "Tweet" things "twats"; so if you're going to do this at least make sure a derogatory pun isn't possible on top of it. Just use a real descriptive word, like "watch" or "subscribe".

Comment: I.e. Custom vocabulary is not "out of the box"; it's about as far into the box as you can get.

Comment: @JasonC: Thank you for bringing some counterbalance to the discussion. I agree with you that using "hip" words is going to scare of a great deal of users. I guess it depends on the target audience of the web app (sorry, I mean internet application) whether you will go for "hip" neology or using simple effective descriptive vocabulary. A business application needs to present itself in a different manner than a teenager app. I just wanted to bring another angle to the existing list of answers. This is certainly not "the right" answer to the question.

Comment: Hmm, if you like AND follow something, I would call you a sheep. Maybe a sheep icon???

Comment: New terms are great if they're also intuitive. Be careful not to alienate and overwhelm your users with new terms. Google 'Circles' is just friends lists, or groups, but I don't know what it is without reading about it.

Answer (score 47):

Personally I like love which is often represented by an icon of a heart and popular in social media. Then you dont have to write the word **love** but simply use the heart.

[image]

But if you don't **like** the heart icon, you can always find a synonym from [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/like):

[image]

Comment: "Don't forget to derive pleasure from us!"

Comment: ***Wesley Murch** and **3 others** luxuriate in this.*

Comment: I stuck on this answer

Comment: booking.com has hearts in their 'liking/bookmarking' mechanism. seems OK.

Comment: Wow, I really get a kick out of this post. +1 and hankered for!

Comment: I'm glad I got to feast on this content.

Comment: So attractive screenshot, I've immediately tried to pull the sliders handles just to see that it's an image :)

Comment: Tried the heart once in a design... personally I like the connotation <3 . But the client thought it had something to do with health care...

Comment: Click HERE to feast on this link to an aggregate of an aggregate of snippets of an aggregate blog linking to original content via 5 degrees of "via" and a broken slide show!

Answer (score 29):

What about **Star**? Google Reader did this and it was pretty clear it went into the Starred Items folder and your friends would also see you starred an item; it also served to bookmark.

The other thing I was just thinking is that unless you told people, no matter what term you used it would still be unclear you "liked" that *user.* That seems totally different to me than liking a post by someone... I may not *want* to like the user themselves, just their one post I found interesting.

Comment: Star seems like the obvious choice. It's used in Chrome, GitHub, Gmail, probably lots of other places.

Answer (score 20):

I think "Favourite" is the nicest commonly used internet term that encompasses the ideas of "like" and "bookmark".

Comment: And for those using Internet Explorer browsers, wouldn't they be confused as to whether the intent is to _bookmark_ the page (put in Favorites) or do something else?

Comment: @PhilPerry "And for those using Internet Explorer browsers, wouldn't they be confused" YES.

Answer (score 11):

Have you heard about **reactions**? You can see how Fastcompany.com is using it on [some of their blogposts](http://www.fastcolabs.com/3032642/why-the-music-industrys-next-big-disruption-is-in-the-recording-studio?partner=newsletter) and the full documentation of it here: http://www.readrboard.com/.

I've take a look at it and responding to your question, this technology allows your users or visitors to select the *type of impression* they have about what they are reading/viewing. I believe this has an advantage where by users creating impressions such as: *interesting* or even *duh!* other users may share those same impressions and let the site admin or content designer what is the content impact.

Take a look at the most popular reactions of users in certain sites:

[image]

Comment: Never been a big fan of this pattern, I've noticed Buzzfeed uses it. Just seems to splinter reactions into something harder to sort by (no universal "quality" metric). I'd want to be very sure you *need* all those emotions/statements as opposed to a binary choice or a rating scale.

Comment: Isn't that a "tag cloud", with the most common tags/responses largest? I agree that other than most-to-least popular (by size), it doesn't show all that much useful information.

Comment: @PhilPerry, what I wanted to illustrate here are __alternatives__ to the "like, +1 and favorite" words. It looks like a tag cloud because they are words that users choose the most.

Answer (score 9):

I think there are a couple that you could use that have good iconography:

**Pound It!** or **Fist Bump It!**

[image] [image]  [image]

and (in my best Borat voice)

**High Five!**

[image] [image] [image]

***Important Note:*** When you click the high five icon it should always play the corresponding **[sound](http://www.theunticket.com/audio/drops//Movie%20-%20Borat%20-%20High%20five.mp3)**!

Comment: "Pound it". Hm. Maybe it's just my dirty mind..

Comment: Isn't that strongly cultural dependent? I think a fist bump, high five, or (!) a booty bump could be misunderstood by many people, unless you have a _very_ limited and homogeneous set of visitors.

Comment: @PhilPerry - I would think that a fist bump or high five is pretty universal.  Just look at sports all around the world.  They all do it.  You could even include "chest bump" to your "booty bump".

Comment: OK, is your 80 year old grandmother going to understand what a fist bump is? How about someone from a foreign culture where intimate personal contact is strongly frowned upon (and they don't even shake hands)?

Comment: @PhilPerry - First of all, yes, she's cool like that. Secondly, I think you may be diving a *tad* too deep. These are simply alternatives that are outside the box which have a bit of humor attached. There was never a *specific* target audience mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: I had never heard of a "chest bump" or "booty bump" (but then, I'm not into sports), but I am not convinced those even work across all genders within even one culture. That said, while I vaguely remember seeing people do a fist bump once or twice, I am still rather alienated by the gesture and definitely by the icon, which to me would signal "get in a fight over this post" rather than "express your agreement with this post".

Comment: You don't want to use "pound it". At least not in public.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - That's shocking to me that you've never heard of a "chest bump" or "booty bump". Regardless, like I said above, this answer was meant to have a "humorous" flair to it and I think it has.  But they are also serious contenders depending on the target demographic / audience.

Answer (score 8):

This is very interesting and immediately reminds me of Pinterest. Pinterest has two different actions one called "Pin", which basically bookmarks that item, which most of us can assume that if you are pinning something then you also like it. However, Pinterest also has an option to like a pin.

Why would you need the option to have both, when would you want to like something without bookmarking it, or in Pinterest's case "Pinning" it.

[image: pinterest]

I think @Bart said it best, go outside of the box and create a new action word. It is a pattern that I think has been used for quite some time and people will understand it.

Another website that is also doing this is Yummly.

[image: yummyl]

Answer (score 6):

Changing the perspective can open other options.

Taking **the user's perspective and benefit** as the primary lens, you can come up with words like :

- keep
- save
- collect

These words tell you about **the value for you as a user** and change the focus that is often put onto the **contents themselves** which eventually get the benefit of the user's action (*distinction*, *election*, etc.) as this often results in words such as "like", "star", etc.

Comment: I'd use this perspective and think about how the 'saved feeds' list is going to be called.

Comment: @doctoraw Maybe the user's "*collection*", "*notepad*", "*nuggets*", "*treasure*", "*savings*", "*bookshelf*", "*drawer*", "*portfolio*"... ;-)

Comment: I agree. If it's going to be called 'collection' the perfect word would be 'collect', and so on..

Comment: Two very different semantics. Bookmarking (for myself) vs. liking (telling others)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can come up with a phenomenon taken from the context of your app. Take Pinterest as an example, where you "pin" something on you pinboard. Is there some action in the real world that would reflect what you are trying to do?

It is a bit hard to come up with something without the context of your app, but if we are to keep it a bit more general here are my favourite suggestions (prioritized):

- Bookmark
- Favourite (very established term, why re-invent?)
- Recommend (unfortunately a bit ambiguous, due to the fact that most people use - recommend when you are sending a link to someone specific)
- Star
- Cherish (IMO the best one from the synonyms posted above)
- Admire

Comment: I Cherish Cherish

Answer (score 4):

What is the utility to 'liking' items, in respect to your product context & brand?

Think of a verb that reinforces the brand:

- If you have an academic product, you might choose "cite"
- If it's a competitive scenario, choose "promote"

These are just a couple simple examples

Comment: Except that, within academia, "cite" has a specific meaning and that ain't it. While you might, for example, say to somebody "I liked/+1'ed/hearted your comment", saying "I cited your comment" would likely receive the response, "What, you included it in the references of your paper?!?"

Comment: I am suggesting that a site may best implement a "like" feature if there is **utility** to the action  of 'liking' - e.g. by having a meaningful result to the 'like', not just fire-and-forget.  One such utility would be to later pull a selection of 'likes' into a citation list for one's own article or thesis.

Answer (score 4):

I have used "Recommend" for forum posts in the past, and simply displaying the number of recommendations in a button next to each post. Rolling over the post adds "Recommendations: " in front of the button to explain it a little. It appears to work well - I appreciate not exactly the same use-case as yours, but you might like it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about "vote it up", I think. Sounds quite neutral and not facebookish.
"upvote" probably goes too, but it is a bit stackexchangish ;-)

*tag* and *bookmark* don't seem to be synonyms of *like*.

Comment: I would probably word it "upvote" or "up vote" or "up-vote" instead, but I agree with the *tag* and *bookmark* statement.

Comment: @CodeMaverick look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177800/upvote-vs-vote-up) my question ;-)  "Outside Stack Exchange, where the concept of upvotes and downvotes isn't so prevalent, using the verb upvote might be met with a raised eyebrow"

Comment: Possibly, but I tend to think it sounds more grammatically correct as "up vote" than "vote up". It seems it would probably have to be "vote it up" or "vote this up" to be grammatically correct that way.

Comment: @Code vote it up? Agree, better.

Comment: How is an **up**-vote *neutral*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper oops. "vote it up" is neutral, "upvote" - no. Made a small mess after edit. Do you think I should exclude "upvote" at all? Or not? My post is at the end of the page now :(

Comment: @nicael: Why is *vote it up* neutral? I don't understand. The first idea that comes to my mind when I read *vote it up* is that it is the *positive* counterpart of *vote it down*.

Comment: How about simply 'vote'?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Neutral, no; but neutral is more of an action of "doing nothing."  It's more how "like" is the positive form and "dislike" is its negative counterpart and how "thumbs up" is the positive form and "thumbs down" is its negative counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

I use a word in day-to-day life ["Me gusta"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=me%20gusta). Though it is spanish but being a popular meme term I think any user can relate to this.

Answer (score 1):

There are very interesting and innovative answers being given, but I think you'd have to explain your requirement a little more so as to make the right decision. For example,

- Does everyone know how many people have bookmarked an item?
- Does the original poster know that he is not bookmarked / followed?
- What if that user is already bookmarked and you click on the button again, does it show liked/loved by default?

I would try to answer these question to further break the expectations you have from the user, and then think about alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you require for showing appreciation ('liking') items in a feed, I think an icon based thumbsup/thumbsdown or heart/broken heart would work well...

This way, users can simply rate or not rate a feed item without it be closely associated with another web app and overcomes the problem of finding the right term to fit in with your app that users will not get confused over.

Like the below for example...

[image: Rating Buttons]

I guess the perfect choice for particular app though will largely come down to what expected action(s) happen after the like. For example:-

Are you going to:-

- Remember a user's likes/dislikes and tweak the feed items displayed to them based on their preference?
- Allow user's to bookmark/save for later reading.
- Allow user's to add to favourites.
- Allow ratings to be viewed by other user's of your app.
- Can you befriend others in your app and see friends ratings.